# Task View shortcut key only works for main monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 with two monitors. When I click on the Task View shortcut on either screen's taskbar (or if I press Windows-Tab), I get the task view displayed on the main screen, and only the windows on that screen are shown in the Task View.

Is there a way to see the Task View for the windows which are on my second screen? Task View seems useful, but a bit pointless if it only works on the main monitor

Comment: Just to be clear, this question relates to the new Task View in Windows 10, which I believe is not the same as Task Manager

Comment: I removed task-manager tag.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the solution is to right-click >> Properties on the taskbar then uncheck "Show taskbar on all displays". The taskbar will no longer be shown on your secondary monitor, but Task View then works across both monitors.

[image]